Equivalent of Lightroom's "Match total exposure" in Capture One
Suppose I have three photos, with the same aperture and ISO. One is shot at 1/60 and the others are shot at 1/120. In Lightroom, I could select all three images, click "Match Total Exposures," and if the first one was selected, it would automatically increase the exposure of the other two by 1 EV, technically matching the exposures of the three pictures.
Is there anything similar in Capture One? I've tried the Normalize tool, but either I'm using it wrong, or it does not offer the same functionality.
